# have serilog logs reference the code where the log originated

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

For example right now I'm getting this log from serilog:

> The query uses the 'First'/'FirstOrDefault' operator without 'OrderBy'
> and filter operators. This may lead to unpredictable results.

and this is it, no stacktrace, some `File.cs` and line number, nothing.

**How do I make serilog write where this log has originated from (file, line number) ?**

this is my current `appsettings.json` serilog configuration:

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information"
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "./logs/log.json",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"
      }
    }
  ]
```

in `Program.cs` I'm setting it up like this:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog(
        (context, configuration) => configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));
```

Comment: Serilog doesn't have that information because you compiled your application in Release mode.

Comment: @IanKemp I'm building in Debug, the Console app (started by VS) is also not showing any file and linenumber info (Console header is `...bin\Debug\.net8.0\WebUI.exe` )

Comment: @IanKemp I've also added ElmahCore, and elmah is showing the a big part of the .cs file and red text at the line where the log (error) started

Answer (score 1):

You could try following sample:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
Log.Logger= new LoggerConfiguration()
   .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
   .CreateLogger();
try
{
    throw new Exception("test error");
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error( ex,"");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

Comment: tried this in my Program.cs and the result is the same as in your picture, so it shows, the file and the line;
however if I call this `Log.Error(new Exception(), "error test log recorded");` in a Test action, I'm not getting the file and line number in the log